# Can't config Java Spring Boot data session Mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, session

I've been using this guide to set up spring session data with mongodb

https://docs.spring.io/spring-session-data-mongodb/docs/2.1.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#introduction

However I am having problems with configuration. I'm using Mongodb with Spring boot and I'm trying to config my session time and session name for Spring boot web application, but it keeps defaulting to 30 minutes and the collection name in mongodb is still 'sessions'

These are what I have tried:

Added these to application.properties:

```
server.session.timeout=1
spring.session.mongodb.collection-name=TestSESSIONS
```

and this

```
server.servlet.session.timeout=60s
spring.session.mongodb.collection-name=TestSESSIONS
```

none of those config work

I've looked over this [URL](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html) for spring common application properties for mongodb but none of it help to config the session time and collection name for mongodb.

After doing hours of research it seems like spring boot uses some kind of autoconfig with this `"org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure"`

so then I added this in my application.properties

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoAutoConfiguration
```

to disable the autoconfigure.

but now it just give me this error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of method mongoSessionRepository in org.springframework.session.data.mongo.config.annotation.web.http.MongoHttpSessionConfiguration required a bean of type 'org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoOperations' that could not be found.

The following candidates were found but could not be injected:
    - Bean method 'mongoTemplate' in 'MongoDataAutoConfiguration' not loaded because AnyNestedCondition 0 matched 2 did not; NestedCondition on MongoDataAutoConfiguration.AnyMongoClientAvailable.FallbackClientAvailable @ConditionalOnBean (types: com.mongodb.client.MongoClient; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans of type com.mongodb.client.MongoClient; NestedCondition on MongoDataAutoConfiguration.AnyMongoClientAvailable.PreferredClientAvailable @ConditionalOnBean (types: com.mongodb.MongoClient; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans of type com.mongodb.MongoClient


Action:

Consider revisiting the entries above or defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoOperations' in your configuration.
```

this is the @bean from the spring.io guide `'mongoSessionConverter'` from above link

this is the java file [MongoHttpSessionConfiguration](https://github.com/myszon01/spring-session/blob/master/spring-session/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/data/mongo/config/annotation/web/http/MongoHttpSessionConfiguration.java) from spring that that's autoconfig by spring; I have tried extending `"MongoHttpSessionConfiguration"` and overriding the setter methods my self. Such as the `"setMaxInactiveIntervalInSeconds"` for sessionTime and 
`"setCollectionName"` for mongododb database collection name.
but I've have this error:

```
Description:

The bean 'mongoSessionRepository', defined in class path resource [com/khatpass/app/config/SessionListenerConfig.class], could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in class path resource [org/springframework/session/data/mongo/config/annotation/web/http/MongoHttpSessionConfiguration.class] and overriding is disabled.
```

I am stuck on trying to configure spring boot session with Mongodb. The session always defaulting to 30 minutes and the collection name is always 'sessions' in mongodb collections. Not sure how to change that `serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms'` and mongodb collections name "sessions" I don't know what to do, need help.

```
2019-02-24 13:39:54.501  INFO 36113 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Cluster created with settings {hosts=[localhost:27017], mode=MULTIPLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
```

Comment: Where do you write these configurations into? In your applications.properties file which was created from spring?

Comment: yes in "/app/src/main/resources/application.properties"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing so much research and then finally, going through the source code, I found the solution:

```
@EnableMongoHttpSession(maxInactiveIntervalInSeconds = 24 * 60 * 60)
public class SessionConfiguration {}
```

To override the default collection name, there is another annotation attribute `collectionName`.

This is working for Spring Boot 2.1.1

Answer (score 1):

After looking over the class [MongoOperationsSessionRepository](https://github.com/myszon01/spring-session/blob/master/spring-session/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/data/mongo/MongoOperationsSessionRepository.java) from `org.springframework.session.data.mongo` it seems like it can't be config through `application.properties` because the class is using static final values

```
public static final int DEFAULT_INACTIVE_INTERVAL = 1800;
```

and

```
public static final String DEFAULT_COLLECTION_NAME = "sessions";
```

only way to change the value is intercept the object before it gets saved. No getters or setters for those fields, it can't be change in an easy way, what a joke!